# Counting measure has no Lebesgue decomposition proof verification

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

I am working through exercises in Rudin RCA but I have some questions about whether my justification is valid as it differs from other posts on the site.

> Let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure on $(0,1)$ and let $\lambda$ be the counting measure on the $\sigma$-algebra of all Lebesgue measurable sets in $(0,1)$. Then $\lambda$ has no Lebesgue decomposition relative to $\mu$.

My attempt is as follows.

Let $\lambda$ denote the counting measure and $\mu$ denote the Lebesgue measure both on the $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets on $(0,1)$. Firstly, fix $ E\in \mathcal{M}$, such that $\lambda(E)=0$. By the definition of the counting measure, $E$ must be the empty set. Therefore, $\mu(E)=0$ so $\mu \ll \lambda$. Now assume there is a Lebesgue decomposition of $\lambda$. Then there are positive measures $\lambda_a$ and $\lambda_s$ such that $\lambda = \lambda_a + \lambda_s$ such that $\lambda_a \ll \mu$ and $\lambda_s \perp \mu$. However, if $\mu(E)=0$, then $\lambda_a(E) =0$ but all countable measurable subsets of $(0,1)$ have Lebesgue measure zero, therefore, it must be that $\lambda_a = 0$. This implies that $\lambda = \lambda_s$. We already have that $\mu \ll \lambda \implies \mu \ll \lambda_s$ and $\mu \perp \lambda_s$ so by 6.8 Proposition (g), $\lambda_s = \lambda = 0$ which is a contradiction. Therefore, there is no Lebesgue decomposition of $\lambda$.

Is my reasoning valid for concluding that $\lambda_a=0$?

Comment: You don't really say how you conclude that $\lambda_a=0$.